# Locating a cross-server memory leak

Tags: php, apache, memory-leaks, elgg

I have a social network based on elgg open source platform (PHP) and I've been having some memory related problems with it.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 12582912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 23456789 bytes) in somefile.php
```

My web application architecture contains 2 apache web servers (linux) with a load balancer between them. about 3-4 times a day the web application collapses and it takes about 2-3 mins for it to go back up again by its own. Knowingly this is just a patch (an ugly one as well) I upgraded the memory on both of the servers and I updated the php.ini to memory_limit = 512M.
I know i still need to locate the memory leak but i just wanted to see how bad was it, and to see if it actually helps.

My real question is: since i have two web servers running the code, how come the entire application collapse and not just one of the servers each time?

Thanks in advance,
Itay

Comment: Presumably the same condition occurs for both at the same time - maybe there's a cron or something that's doing something inefficient on lots of records. What does `somefile.php` do?

Comment: there are no cron jobs on the servers and it's a diffrent php file that throws the error each time...

Comment: You have effective memory limit of 12MB. Try updating the settings in .htaccess file that's likely to be overriding php.ini

Comment: Thanks Pawel, you were right about my .htaccess overriding the php.ini

Comment: @ItayWeiss - you should add this as answer, as this question is still on unanswered list :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the problem was that the settings in the .htaccess file were overriding the php.ini.

I figured it out thanks to [Pawel Sroka's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1541247/pawe%C5%82-sroka) comment.